# Как сформировать следующий curl запрос в PHP

Tags: curl

Как сформировать такой запрос через PHP?

```
curl -L https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/hashes
        -H 'X-API-ID:7e26bb94aa2ce44e6e16aca6ae6d28c7f0157b5ccd7a82f86bbbe8d835effd71'
        -H 'X-API-KEY:5112486af64b2f97bd3742c4153cee32452549491480cfd164b336720b82a84d'
```

Формат ответа — JSON.

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: как его сформировать в php

Comment: я не понмаю, как его составить, многие варианты перепробовал из инетрнета